# Setting some initial text in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have the following code

```
var dbvalue = "Ned";
var deleteLink = '<a href="#delete" onclick="deleteMe();">Delete</a>';
var editLink = '<a href="#save" onclick="saveMe();">Save</a>';
//newemployee.setAttribute("id", "Lorem_ipsum");
newEmployee.innerHTML="<input type = checkbox>" + "First name: <input>" + "Last name: <input>"  +deleteLink + "" +editLink +"<br/>"+"<br/>";
```

and i am wondering how i would go about having my variable dbvalue fill in the value it holds in my field First name.How can it be done?.

Comment: Can you show what HTML you're trying to end up with?

Comment: I want to have a checkbox,then a firstname label,then the first name input,then the lastname label, and finally the lastname input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it this way:

```
var dbvalue = "Ned";
var deleteLink = '<a href="#delete" onclick="deleteMe();">Delete</a>';
var editLink = '<a href="#save" onclick="saveMe();">Save</a>';
//newemployee.setAttribute("id", "Lorem_ipsum");
newEmployee.innerHTML="<input type = checkbox>" + "First name: <input value=\"" + dbvalue + "\" type=\"text\">" + "Last name: <input>"  +deleteLink + "" +editLink +"<br/>"+"<br/>";
```

Highlighting the First Name part alone

```
"First name: <input value=\"" + dbvalue + "\" type=\"text\">"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
newEmployee.innerHTML="<input type = checkbox>" + "First name: <input type='text' value='" + dbvalue + "'>" + "Last name: <input>"  +deleteLink + "" +editLink +"<br/>"+"<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `addElement` and `addTextNode` to add elements to the DOM, but that's up to you.
Inputs don't use `innerHTML`. They use value. So an example text with your dbvalue would be:

```
"First name: <input type=\"text\" value=\""+dbvalue+"\" />" //The slash there is for XHTML. You can leave it out if you want.
```